# SQL Server deadlock: How to read this log?

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me interpret this log? How do i solve this issue? I'm using Serialized as my Isolation Level and I think this is the issue. Also, I do know this deadlock has something to do with the Company table.

Please bare with my lack of SQL skills. Im new at it.

**Update**
I don't get any matching records when I try to get the object using the following query:

```
 select * from sysobjects where id = 72057594047692800
```

[image: Log]

[image: Company Table]

Comment: [SQL Server technical bulletin - How to resolve a deadlock](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524)

Comment: [Troubleshooting Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937573(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: [Analyze Deadlocks with SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx)

Comment: Please post the actual deadlock XML, not a picture. See [Save Deadlock Graphs (SQL Server Profiler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx)